# VPS gpu not running when no RDP connection

Tags: remote-desktop, vps

I want to stream a Zoom meeting from a VPS server (basically sharing an app screen) - it works fine, the only problem is, if I don't maintain the RDP connection, the Zoom meeting screen goes blank. Doing some search I think the reason is something like this I found "Windows uses a virtualized GPU for rdp connections. As soon as you disconnect rdp, this virtualized gpu is removed. As soon as you reconnect the virtualized gpu is added again." .. So is there any way of fixing this, so the virtualized gpu runs constantly, whether there is an rdp connection or not?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don’t use an RDP connection? There are other protocols like VNC. In fact, why do this at all? Just join the meeting, the end.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, i am hosting the meeting to share an app running on a vps. But if I don't keep an RDP connection open to the vps, the meeting screen share just goes blank.